# Copy/paste of URL to contenteditable convert url to hyperlink in Internet Explorer - How to prevent that?

Tags: internet-explorer, sitecore, contenteditable

I have a project where the webmasters can edit content in fields with contenteditable="true". It's a project in Sitecore by the way.

If the user works in Internet Explorer and copy/paste a URL into the field, it's automatically converted to a hyperlink, with a

```
<a href=""></a>
```

around the URL.

Is there any way this can be prevented, as the user is only supposed to insert a textatring, and not HTML in the fields.

When googling around, I found out that it looks like a "feature" in IE, but in this case it's a big problem.

Any pointers would be highly appreciated?

Comment: What is the Field type?

Comment: `document.execCommand("AutoUrlDetect", false, false);` works in IE 9 but doesn't seem to work in IE 11.

Comment: It's just a span-element with the contenteditable="true" attribute on it.